# Databricks spark UDF not working on filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, databricks

I came across an issue in Databricks with Pyspark and I'm trying to understand why this implementation is not working, if I'm missing something conceptual here.
What I'm trying to do is to run a UDF on a column in a dataframe but only on non-null values.

If I replace the lstrip_udf call with a fix value like "Val123" then it works fine, however it doesn't work for UDF. If I implement a null check inside the UDF with a bit different implementation then it works too.
But even though there is the **when** and the **IsNotNull** it still throws the below error.

Can someone explain why or what am I missing here to make this work?

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, BooleanType, TimestampType
inputschema = StructType([StructField("testcol", StringType(), True),
                          StructField("testcol2", StringType(), True)
                         ]
                        )
inputfile = spark.createDataFrame([("012121212","Ref #1"),
                                   ("0034343434","Ref #2"),
                                   ("0034343434","Ref #3"),
                                   (None,"Ref #4"),
                                   (None,"Ref #5"),
                                   ("00998877","Ref #6")
                                  ],
                                  schema = inputschema
                                 )
#display(inputfile)

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit
column_name = "testcol"
lstrip_udf = udf(lambda s: s.lstrip().lstrip("0"), StringType())
outputfile = (inputfile.withColumn(column_name,
                                  when(col(column_name).isNotNull(),
                                       lstrip_udf(col(column_name)) #replace this line with "Val123" and it works
                                      )
                                 ))
display(outputfile)
```

Error:

```
File "<command-3701821159856508>", line 18, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug in Spark, so here is a minor modification to the UDF which solves the problem:

```
lstrip_udf = udf(lambda s: s.lstrip().lstrip("0") if s is not None else None, StringType())
```

Or you can use Spark SQL to do this, which is more efficient than using UDF:

```
outputfile = (
    inputfile.withColumn(column_name,
        F.when(col(column_name).isNotNull(),
            F.expr("ltrim('0', ltrim('',testcol))")
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I think you might be right @mck: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19844. It looks like someone has marked the ticket as "resolved" but didn't comment, so it's not clear how it was :s

Comment: @user6386471 it says `Labels: bulk-closed` ;)

Comment: I've come across that spark issue 19844 too but since it was "Resolved" I thought the issue was addressed. Hence my question if I was missing something conceptual here but if I understand correctly this is still a bug and the case 19844 linked above was set to "Resolved" without an actual fix...in that case I'm glad that my understanding was correct and this is indeed a bug, thanks :)